# Typescript import/export giving "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"

Tags: typescript

I have an asp.net core project using typescript. I am using import/export syntax  like this:

```js
import ConfigurationDocument from "./Configuration Document";
import  ServiceEndpoint  from "./Service - Endpoints";

export default class ConfigurationDocumentManager
```

The project builds fine but when I try to navigate to a page consuming the ts linked like this:

```
<script src="/js/Manager - Configuration Document.js" type="module"></script>
```

I get errors:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

The file naming conventions is the standard at my workplace, so I don't know if that's the problem. The project builds and runs fine if I put the all ts files in wwwroot, remove the tsconfig and remove all imports/exports so I don't think it's the problem.

My tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": [ "ES2020", "DOM" ],
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/",
    "module": "ES2020"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I'm sure this is something obvious but I've been googling this for days, and tried dozens of solutions but nothing has worked. If someone could just show me a working tsconfig file that would be great.

My project is like:

```
>root
    >wwwroot
    >TypeScript
    (c# files etc)
```

Comment: Try Removing spaces from your filenames.

Comment: @MuhammadDanialIqbal - It shouldn't make the slightest difference.

Comment: Does the script tag you've quoted exist **literally** as shown in the HTML being sent to the browser? I ask for two reasons: 1. It obviously does have `type="module"`. :-) So the error's really weird (but that's probably why you're asking about it!) and 2. The `~` in the `src` is odd. It looks like the shortcut for the home directory on \*nix systems.

Comment: In the browser the tag is : ```<script src="/js/Manager - Configuration Document.js" type="module"></script>```

Comment: @ekke - I suggested editing the question to show that.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate the problem locally. Those files with those `import`/`export`s (provided I end the `class`) and that `tsconfig.json` works just fine (with slight changes to paths because of the different environments). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including the `package.json` needed to build, etc. But please keep it minimal. :-)

Comment: I'll try to make one, but from what you've said I expect that the error must be somewhere else in the project and I won't be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I wasn't able to replicate the error in an example. Due to the scope of the project I will leave it and just use a flat file structure without imports but it's really annoying that this isn't working. Thanks anyway.